# Asking for help in order to improve a paper

Tags: discussion

I have written a paper recently. The reviewers were intrested in the material of the paper the topic and its novility but unfortunately they had  serious concerns about the quality of its English.

I just wanted to ask you friends, how is it possible to improve the quality of my paper using this place. I mean is it possible to break some parts of the paper into smaller parts  and ask you friends to help me to improve it?

Thank you so much....

Comment: if you have specific questions about spelling, grammar and word choice we would be delighted to help. Critique of style and proofreading, though, are off-topic. You may also be able to get help [here](http://writers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Questions such as "Does the word *novility* exist?" or "What is the difference between *how it is possible... .* and *how is it possible...?* would be welcome here **so long as** you have done some research of your own, and need help interpreting the results.  If you ask without any background, many people are likely to assume you are just too lazy to do the work yourself.

And, as Brian said, proofreading is off-topic; 'how to improve this piece' is both off-topic and primarily opinion-based.